# How can I make a configuration web page for a linux appliances? Any pre made solutions available?

Tags: configuration, embedded, raspberry-pi, webmin

I am putting together a bunch of embeded linux appliances that we will be installing at a few locations. Built the whole thing from scratch using Raspbian (debian based) and Raspberry Pis.

There are a few things to configure inside it, a custom config file, freetds, network settings, and a bunch of other stuff...

I know I can put apache on there and develop the whole thing DIY style but there has to be a customizable linux web based dashboard/config page project out there somewere... Its almost unthinkable that no one would have thought of that.

I found a bunch of cpanel types of soltions and Webmin packages but they are really aimed at service providers for VPS services and websites or server administration. All I want is something simple to offer a web page like on home routers and be able to customize which options are configurable. It could even be real simple with only links that opens config files and allows editing them right on the web page.

Thank you.

Comment: Just to make sure we're on the same page, is there any reason you can't use SSH to connect to the appliance and edit config files using standard tools like vi, emacs, nano, etc.? Exposing config files over a web interface could certainly be a security concern.

Comment: What about `webmin` doesn't suit your needs? That's the usual suggestion whenever someone asks this sort of question.

Comment: I want to offer the technicians that are linux illiterate the possibility to configure the equipment and do basic support. I was under the impression that webmin was for administering a whole server, users, shares etc.. I dont want them to touch that. I will look at it in more details and repport back.